# Flex DropDownList items not clickable

Tags: actionscript-3, apache-flex, flex4

I'm working on a Flex app and am having problems with a DropDownList - clicking on any item in the list just closes the list instead of selecting the item. I don't just mean that my change event isn't getting called - the currently selected item on the dropdown visibly doesn't change.

The DropDownList uses the default skinning. Here's the code:

```
<s:VGroup width="100%" horizontalAlign="center" verticalAlign="middle">
    <s:Label text="Make a selection:" />
    <s:DropDownList id="dropdownList" dataProvider="{optionsArrayList}" width="100%" selectedIndex="0" change="_onListSelectionChange(event);" />
</s:VGroup>
```

Why would clicking a list item close the list without changing the selection?

Comment: That should work but I think that the problem is in your `_onListSelectionChange()` function, could you show its code ?

Comment: That's not the problem; that function doesn't even get called. If I completely remove the _onListSelectionChange() function and "change" property, the selection still doesn't change when I try clicking on a different item.

Comment: Your code looks fine, I don't see any other thing that can be the origin of your problem. Did you have something else in your code or the stage ? Also, did you see your data in your list when testing ? ...

Comment: Maybe something is overlapping your opened list and the list behaves as if you would just click somewhere else on the stage? Also try to remove the VGroup, maybe that is clipping the contents

Comment: Could you have overwritten the selected styles?  Sometimes something is selected, but it doesn't look like it.  Can you interact with the selectedItem / selectedIndex?  Can you share a sample data provider?  Or a more complete sample?